# Heroku gives error on ActiveScaffold routing "as_routes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, heroku, activescaffold

I'm trying to get my Rails3 application running on Heroku,the first time I've tried to use Heroku. The app uses the ActiveScaffold plugin for Rails3. It works in production mode locally, and Heroku takes the app OK, but when I browse to the app I get a message "App crashed". The logs show

```
/routes.rb:34: undefined local variable or method `as_routes' for <ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x2b23d0ca4a08> (NameError)
```

`as_routes` is the ActiveScaffold-generated route, such as

```
  resources :contacts do as_routes end
```

It looks at first glance as if Heroku is not recognizing the ActiveScaffold methods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

does it support rails3?

> Active Scaffold master currently supports rails-2.3.8

but Heroku doesn't do anything special to your app in this instance though - strange how it works locally though...?

Comment: ActiveScaffold has a fork that works with Rails3, which is in fact the whole point of the fork, at https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold. Like you, I don't know why the plugin would work for me locally but not on Heroku; I suppose it must be something about the way I have configured it.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the example here [setup-activescaffold-rails-3](http://vhochstein.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/setup-activescaffold-rails-3/) and it worked locally (using Rails 3.0.3). I've not tried Heroku, but maybe that's what the original poster is using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem occurred because of the way ActiveScaffold was installed as a plugin and was not included in the git repository. I tried simply removing folder from the .gitignore file and making sure it was in the repository, but that didn't work, giving the same error. Then I saw that ActiveScaffold can be installed as a plugin. I did that, synced with Heroku, and the error disappeared. Unfortunately, another error took its place,

```
fileutils.rb:1263:in `initialize': Permission denied - /disk1/home/slugs/.../mnt/public/javascripts/active_scaffold/default/date_picker_bridge.js
```

but that is material for another question.